# MP3 Metadata look up API for Java (Find ID3 data)

Tags: java, database, mp3, metadata, id3

I am working on a Java app that will find songs and rename them based on user input and ID3 metadata.

I have found quite a few Java libraries for editing/retrieving song metadata from a file but I'm wondering if there is some online database with ID3 tag information that my program could interact with.

For example say there is a file WeWillRockYou.mp3
The file name is the title but the metadata is empty or wrong
Is there somewhere to look up the metadata online (to fill in Artist=Queen etc)?
Or is this something that will require paying for a service?

Comment: Looking further I'm starting to think that fingerprinting is the petter way to go

Comment: Have a look at the gracenote api. https://developer.gracenote.com. There if a Java API too. https://github.com/richadams/java-gracenote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an API that does what I need.
I'm using the EchoNest API for Java called jEn 
https://code.google.com/p/jen-api/